# Android multi size screen and mipmap images in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, mipmaps

i have a problem in my project,in  this project includes all layout folders for multi size application .

layouts:

layout/fragment_second.xml

layout-large/fragment_second.xml/

layout-xlarge/fragment_second.xml

layout-small/fragment_second.xml

**and a image copied in all mipmap folders:**

mipmap-hdpi/about          size:106*106 px

mipmap-mdpi/about          size:68*68 px

mipmap-xhdpi/about         size:130*130 px

mipmap-xxhdpi/about        size:210*210 px

mipmap-xxxhdpi/about       size:260*260 p

load in imageview:

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@mipmap/about"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

problem is: dont use other images for diffrent sizes and just use hdpi folder

I tested app in many devices and i could not resolve it

Manifest:

```
  <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
            android:normalScreens="true"
            android:largeScreens="true"
            android:xlargeScreens="true"
            android:anyDensity="true" />
```

How i can fix this problem

Thank you

Comment: "problem is: dont use other images for diffrent sizes and just use hdpi folder
"  Can you elaborate?

Comment: Does it work any differently if you put everything in the drawable folder instead of the mipmap folder? I believe the mipmap folder is for icons.

Comment: well. how i can solove my problem?

Answer (score 2):

Well, first of all, please be clearer on your question, and use proper English so it is easier for others to understand what you want.

Now, as for your question, the mipmap is only for the Launcher Icons. For everything else, use drawable. The reason for that is that some manufacturers use icons of density different than that of the screen, to say, get larger icons. So mipmap is not useful when you want your image to scale properly. Drawables are your friends, ask for their help.

PS: I can help you better if you are a bit more elaborate on your question.

Comment: Glad to help. Accept my answer, so others can benefit too :)